# list of entity, max date, max row_id

Tags: c#, date, sql-server-2012

I have table in SQLServer.
I have list in c#, of entity id. (ex: 50, 70, 120 etc).
I need, for each entity, to take only the line with max date, and within that, the max of row_id.

for exmaple:

```
entity        date_value       row_id
50            30/06/2017       3000<br>
75            30/04/2017       2900<br>
50            30/06/2017       2890<br>
50            30/05/2017       2500<br>
50            30/06/2017       2100<br>
75            30/03/2017       2000<br>
```

here I need to take only 2 rows:

```
 50            30/06/2017       3000<br>
 75            30/04/2017       2900<br>
```

Not for all entities have rows in this table.

Can u help me with this?

Thank u.

Comment: It`s a good idea to tag Entity Framework or Linq To SQL or simple ADO.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using **Entity Framework** than:

```
  using (var context = new YourAppConext)
  {
     var result = context.Table.GroupBy(x => x.entity).Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.date_value).ThenByDescending(t => t.row_id).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
  }
```

Idea is to have a subsets with the same *entity* then by using select we flatten the group then ordering set and take the data with the largest date and row id - in case of same date recordings.

*Note* if row_id is a string then it`s more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

i think its help you

for ascending use   `OrderBy(x => x.Col1).ThenBy(x => x.Col2)`

Or For Descending use this

```
 OrderByDescending (x => x.Col1).ThenByDescending (x => x.Col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ like below:

```
var res = from t in listName
                          group t by t.entity
                          into g
                          select new
                          {
                              entity = g.Key,
                              date_value = (from t2 in g select t2.date_value).Max(),
                              row_id = (from t3 in g select t3.row_id).Max(),
                          };
```

Comment: It is not necessarily that the highest date is with the max row_id.